# How to correctly implement State Pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

1. An Account could have various states such as Frozen, Active, NotVerified, Closed.
2. And Account could perform following actions: Deposit(), Withdraw(), HolderVerified(), Close(), Freeze()
3. These implementation of these actions could vary depending on current state of the account.

Below is my way of tackling the above scenario. 
However, what if we have a situation where we have to :

**Deduct 10 percent of the deposit when the deposit is made when current state of the account is Frozen?**

**ACCOUNT**

```
    class Account
    {
        public decimal Balance { get; private set; }

        private IAccountState State { get; set; }

        public Account(Action onUnfreeze)
        {
            this.State = new NotVerified(onUnfreeze);
        }

        public void Deposit(decimal amount)
        {
            this.State = this.State.Deposit(() => { this.Balance += amount; });
        }

        public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
        {
            this.State = this.State.Withdraw(() => { this.Balance -= amount; });
        }

        public void HolderVerified()
        {
            this.State = this.State.HolderVerified();
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            this.State = this.State.Close();
        }

        public void Freeze()
        {
            this.State = this.State.Freeze();
        }
    }
```

**IAccountState**

```
interface IAccountState
    {
        IAccountState Deposit(Action addToBalance);
        IAccountState Withdraw(Action substractFromBalance);
        IAccountState Freeze();
        IAccountState HolderVerified();
        IAccountState Close();

    }
```

**Concrete Implementation of IAccountState**

**ACTIVE**

```
class Active : IAccountState
    {
        private Action OnUnfreeze { get; }
        public Active(Action onUnfreeze)
        {
            OnUnfreeze = onUnfreeze;
        }



        public IAccountState Deposit(Action addToBalance)
        {
            addToBalance();
            return this;
        }

    public IAccountState Withdraw(Action substractFromBalance)
    {
        substractFromBalance();
        return this;
    }

    public IAccountState HolderVerified() => this;
    public IAccountState Freeze() => new Frozen(this.OnUnfreeze);
    public IAccountState Close() => new Closed();
}
```

**NOTVERIFIED**

```
class NotVerified : IAccountState
    {
        public Action OnUnfreeze { get; }
        public NotVerified(Action onUnfreeze)
        {
            this.OnUnfreeze = onUnfreeze;
        }
        public IAccountState Close() => new Closed();

        public IAccountState Deposit(Action addToBalance)
        {
            addToBalance();
            return this;
        }

        public IAccountState Freeze() => this;

        public IAccountState HolderVerified() => new Active(this.OnUnfreeze);

        public IAccountState Withdraw(Action substractFromBalance) => this;
    }
```

**How will you deal with the situation when you have to deduct 10 percent of the deposit  when current state of the account is Frozen?**

I am not sure how to modify Deposit method in NotVerified class to meet the requirement :

```
 public IAccountState Deposit(Action addToBalance)
 {
    addToBalance();
    return this;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an enum rather than an interface:

```
enum AccountState
{
    NotVerified,
    Active,
    Frozen,
    Closed
}

class Account
{
    public decimal Balance { get; private set; }

    // I assumed the bank would want to deposit the 10% to its own account        
    public decimal Fees { get; set; }

    public AccountState state {get; private set; } = AccountState.NotVerified;

    public Account() {}

    public void Deposit(decimal amount) {
        if (this.state == AccountState.Active)
            this.Balance += amount;
        else if (this.state == AccountState.Frozen)
        {
            this.Balance += amount * (decimal).9;
            this.Fees += amount * (decimal).1;
        }
    }

    public void Withdraw(decimal amount) {
        if (this.state == AccountState.Active)
            this.Balance -= amount;
    }

    public bool HolderVerified() {
        return (this.state == AccountState.Active);
    }

    public void Close() {
        this.state = AccountState.Closed;
    }

    public void Freeze() {
        this.state = AccountState.Frozen;
    }
}
```